# Returning a JTable from the JPanel class within the table

Tags: java, swing, object, jtable, jpanel

I have the follower class and I want to get the `JTable` that is in.

```
public class TimeTable extends JPanel
{
private JTable table;

public TimeTable (int semestre)
{

    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); 
    table = new JTable(new MyTableModel()); 
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);     
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(510, 350));  //imposta le dimensioni della tabella
    JScrollPane jps = new JScrollPane(table);
    add(jps);
    add(new JScrollPane(table));
    table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    table.setRowHeight(40);
    TableColumn tcol;
    for (int i=0; i<table.getColumnCount(); i++)
    {
        tcol = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
        tcol.setCellRenderer(new CustomTableCellRenderer());

    }
}
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {//instructions that customize my table}
public class CustomTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{//other instructions that customize my table }
}
```

Please note that I don't want to see the table in a Frame. I've  yet done this: now I need to add a `MouseListener` to the table, while the class that I have is a `JPanel` extension.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a getter method to `TimeTable`:

```
public class TimeTable extends JPanel {
    private JTable table;
    ...

    public JTable getTable() {
        return table;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you can get the `JTable` instance if you have a `TimeTable` reference:

```
TimeTable timeTable = new TimeTable(42);
...
JTable table = timeTable.getTable();
```

Comment: that is what I did.. but it was asked to define the method Static. Now instead not.. that's strange. By the way thank (again) you

Comment: You're welcome. If the compiler tells you that a method can't be called because it's not `static`, it means that you are trying to call an instance method from a static context. Normally that is not needed, because usually most code belongs to objects (it's not unusual that `main()` is the only static method).